# How to create Panda Dataframe from csv that is compressed in tar.gz?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, gzip, tar

How can I create the pandas DataFrame from csv file that's compressed in tar.gz? I found this code which does that but with zip file. What should I change in the following code to make it work with tar.gz without downloading the tar.gz and csv file.

```
import pandas, requests, zipfile, StringIO
r =requests.get('http://data.octo.dc.gov/feeds/crime_incidents/archive/crime_incidents_2013_CSV.zip')
z = zipfile.ZipFile(StringIO.StringIO(r.content))
df=pandas.read_csv(z.open('sample_CSV.csv'))
```

My file is https://ghtstorage.blob.core.windows.net/downloads/mysql-2016-06-16.tar.gz

Comment: Note that the zipped file is almost 40gb. This will be unzipped and loaded into memory. How much RAM do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try below for extracting tar.gz as below :

```
import tarfile
tar = tarfile.open(fname, "r:gz")
tar.extractall()
tar.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, Raghav! Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0):

Try simply supply your `.tar.gz` file as the file name
to `read_csv` and it will automatically decompress and open it, 
since this is the default behavior for `gz` files.

Make sure the extension is in lower case.

Comment: Thanks, Israel! Appreciate your response.